# Filtering DataGrid, MVVM, Dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, mvvm, datagrid, entity-framework-4, dynamic-linq

How can I filter my DataGrid items like MS Access filter works (just select by mouse some part of cell and press "Filter" button)?

I have ViewModel MyViewModel with 2 Commands (Filter and ClearFilter) 
and ObservableCollection
I have Model with method GetItems(...);

in DataGrid CellEditEnding event I save selected path and column name:

```
_selectedColumn = e.Column;
if (e.EditingElement is TextBox)
    _selectedText = (e.EditingElement as TextBox).SelectedText;
```

So I have 2 params: my T object's property name, on which it is necessary to sort, and filter value (both are typeof String).

How should I change the Model's method GetItems, what would it work.
Method Model.GetItemws uses EntityFramework to query items from database. 
How can I apply to this query my filter and how I can build this query? Some dynamic LINQ/Expression

```
var items = EFQuery().**Where(myFilter)**.ToList();
```

Where and how should I create this myFilter?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533673/entity-framework-dynamic-where-clause/534061#534061) might help.

Comment: Thanks. It helped with PredicateBuilder and LinqKit

Answer (score 0):

You can write filter lambda like this:

```
.Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(AA).GetValue(x).ToString().Contains(BB))
```

Where AA is variable which contains selected column name

BB is a variable which contains a filter text.

Restriction: Your property AA must be the string or class which having overridden ToString Method