# Collection-valued parameters with The Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

In my last project i decided to use Entity Framework and it was all going well until i try to get datas with *"where in"*, i got an error.

After a tiny search i ve come up with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110314/linq-to-entities-building-where-clauses-to-test-collections-within-a-many-to-ma) and [that post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/).

This is what i am trying to do

```
var all = fooelements
              .Where(l=>controlsToGet
                            .Contains(l.Control.Name));
```

Is there any to handle it with lambda expressions or linq with the Entity Framework ?

Thank you

Comment: "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. Only primitive types (for instance Int32, String and Guid) are supported in this context."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building upon the previous answer I have a tip that makes it easy to do this here:

[Tip 8 - How to write 'WHERE IN' style queries using LINQ to Entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx)

Hope this helps

Alex James

Program Manager - Entity Framework Team

[Entity Framework Tips](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/index-of-tips.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what i am looking for and thank you for the Framework tips link

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to generate a `WHERE IN` clause with EF, but you can use expression trees to construct a `WHERE` clause that will test for each of your values:

```
    Expression<Func<FooEntity, bool>> seed = l => false;
    var predicate = controlsToGet.Aggregate(seed,
        (e, c) => Expression.Lambda<Func<DataEventAttribute, bool>>(
            Expression.OrElse(
                Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.Property(
                        Expression.Property(
                            e.Parameters[0],
                            "Control"),
                        "Name"),
                    Expression.Constant(c)),
                e.Body),
            e.Parameters));

    var all = fooelements.Where(predicate);
```

If you print out `predicate`, you should see an expression like this:

```
l => ((l.Control.Name = ctrl5) || l.Control.Name = ctrl4 || ... || False )
```