# Does Entity Framework 4 support Many-to-Many queries?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have the exact same problem as described in this post (event content / tags objects):

[LINQ to entities - Building where clauses to test collections within a many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110314/linq-to-entities-building-where-clauses-to-test-collections-within-a-many-to-ma#131551)

I am getting the Exception:

Unable to create a constant value of type 'XXX.Tag'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Is this problem resolved in E.F. 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work fine in EF4.0

from tag in db.Tags
where tag.Name.Contains("mytag")
from content in tag.Contents
select content