# how do I combine Expression<Func<MyClass,bool>>[]?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I have an array of

```
Expression<Func<MyClass,bool>>
```

However, I want to AND them all together to get just a single item of that type. How do I do this? Can I cast the result of Expression.And?

Comment: I used PredicateBuilder in the past to do this -- http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: You want the final result to also be `Expression<Func<MyClass,bool>>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the following extension method:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                       Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
{
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.AndAlso (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
}
```

From here: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Then you can just write this to fold them all down to one expression.

```
public Expression<Func<T, bool>> AggregateAnd(Expression<Func<T,bool>>[] input)
{
    return input.Aggregate((l,r) => l.And(r));
}
```

Comment: It ends up that the above code won't actually work for most purposes because Invoke cannot be translated to SQL. I ended finding similar but more compatible code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110314/linq-to-entities-building-where-clauses-to-test-collections-within-a-many-to-m