# Entity Framework LINQ complex query - combine multiple predicates

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a complex Linq query that goes like this:
Get all organisations which have employees that match the given filter parameters.

Example filter:

- Firstname: John
- Name: Smith

My first attempt:

```cs
if (!filter.Name.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    query = query.Where(o => o.Persons.Any(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter.Name.ToLower())));
}

if (!filter.Firstname.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    query = query.Where(o => o.Persons.Any(p => p.Firstname.ToLower().Contains(filter.Firstname.ToLower())));
}

if (!filter.ContactNumber.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    query = query.Where(o => o.Persons.Any(p => p.ContactNumber.contains(filter.ContactNumber)));
}
```

The problem with this approach is that when there is someone with the firstname John (ex. John Johnson) in organisation A, and someone with the last name Smith (Jenny Smith) in organisation A. The organisation (A) that contains those two persons gets returned. Which it shouldn't. I only want organisations that have people with the firstname "john" AND the lastname "Smith"

I found a working, but dirty and non-scalable approach:

```cs
if (!filter.ContactNumber.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    if (!filter.Name.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() && !filter.Firstname.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
    {
        query = query.Where(o => o.Persons.Any(p => p.ContactNumber.contains(filter.ContactNumber)
                                                && p.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter.Name.ToLower())
                                                && p.Firstname.ToLower().Contains(filter.Firstname.ToLower())));
    }
    else if (!filter.Name.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
    {
        query = query.Where(o => o.Persons.Any(p => p.ContactNumber.contains(filter.ContactNumber)
                                                && p.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter.Name.ToLower())));
    } else if (!filter.Firstname.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
    {
        query = query.Where(o => o.Persons.Any(p => p.ContactNumber.contains(filter.ContactNumber)
                                                && p.Firstname.ToLower().Contains(filter.Firstname.ToLower())));
    } else
    {
        query = query.Where(o => o.Persons.Any(p => p.ContactNumber.contains(filter.ContactNumber));
    }
} else if(!filter.Name.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    if (!filter.Firstname.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
    {
        query = query.Where(o => o.Persons.Any(p => p.Firstname.ToLower().Contains(filter.Firstname.ToLower()) && p.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter.Name.ToLower())));
    } else
    {
        query = query.Where(o => o.Persons.Any(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter.Name.ToLower())));
    }
} else if (!filter.Firstname.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    query = query.Where(o => o.Persons.Any(p => p.Firstname.ToLower().Contains(filter.Firstname.ToLower())));
}
```

As you can see this not a very clean solution.

I also tried using method calls inside the expression but Linq couldnt translate that. Is there any way I can can make a list of predicate expressions an merge them to one? Or is there a another, better solution?

By the way, since I need a paginated list, it all has to be in one query.

For your information, this is what my filter class looks like. It is just a class send from my front-end with all the fields that need to be filtered.

```cs
public class ContactFilter
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Firstname{ get; set; }
    public string ContactNummer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What type exactly is `filter`? Doesn't seem like a `Predicate<T>`. Where are its properties coming from?

Comment: Filter is just a simple class with the fields that need to be filtered. Some fields may be null, some not, depends on the which fields are filled in. I edited the description

Comment: Why is your first code not working? It seems to be AND conditions of each value in the filter.

Comment: Btw, contains may need to be replaced with equal.

Comment: The first code was not working because of the explanation below it. And I needed contains since I want to allow partial matches

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way I can can make a list of predicate expressions an merge them to one?

Yes, and that's the approach I'd prefer in this situation.

First build the list:

```
var filterExpressions = new List<Expression<Func<Person, bool>>();
if (!filter.Name.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    filterExpressions.Add(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter.Name.ToLower()));
}

if (!filter.Firstname.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    filterExpressions.Add(p => p.Firstname.ToLower().Contains(filter.Firstname.ToLower()));
}

if (!filter.ContactNumber.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    filterExpressions.Add(p => p.ContactNumber.contains(filter.ContactNumber));
}
```

From there, you can use [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22569086/1159478) to `And` arbitrary Expressions together.  You'll also need to decide what to do if there are no filters to apply (I'll use a default of no filter, but you may want to do something else).

```
var predicate = filterExpressions.DefaultIfEmpty(p => true)
    .Aggregate((a, b) => a.And(b));
```

Now we get to the hard part.  We have an expression that represents the lambda you want to pass to a call to `Any`.  It would be nice if we could just do:

```
query = query.Where(o => o.Persons.Any(predicate));
```

But sadly, this won't work because the type of `o.Persons` isn't an `IQueryable`.  So now we have an expression that we want to embed in another expression in which the inner expression needs to be a lambda.  Fortunately this isn't *too* complicated:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> EmbedLambda
    <TSource, TResult, TFunc1, TFunc2>(
    this Expression<Func<TFunc1, TFunc2>> lambda,
    Expression<Func<TSource, Func<TFunc1, TFunc2>, TResult>> expression)
{
    var body = expression.Body.Replace(
        expression.Parameters[1],
        lambda);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TResult>>(
        body, expression.Parameters[0]);
}
```

(Using a helper class from the above link)

Now we just need to call the method.  Note we won't be able to rely entirely on type inference due to the way this all works out, so some types need to be specified explicitly.

```
query = query.Where(predicate.EmbedLambda((UnknownType o, Func<Person, bool> p) => o.Persons.Any(p)));
```

Comment: *"But sadly, this won't work because the type of `o.Persons` isn't an `IQueryable`..."* But it can easily be maid by adding `.AsQueryable()`, thus eliminating the need of additional expression helpers with ugly calling syntax.

Comment: @IvanStoev Assuming the query provider knows how to translate that, which many will not.  It does not produce a query the same as having inlined the lambda, which is what the query provider is generally expecting to happen.

Comment: Well, generally you are right, but the question has a context (`[entity-framework-core]` tag, that's why I'm landing here). Fortunately the target query provider (EF Core) recognizes the need of such functionality and property handles it.

Answer (score 5):

One of the easiest solution is using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) library:

```cs
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Person>();

if (!filter.Name.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter.Name.ToLower()));
}

if (!filter.Firstname.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Firstname.ToLower().Contains(filter.Firstname.ToLower()));
}

if (!filter.ContactNumber.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    predicate = predicate.And(p => p.ContactNumber.contains(filter.ContactNumber));
}

Expression<Func<Person, bool>> exp = predicate;

query = query
    .AsExpandable()
    .Where(o => o.Persons.Any(exp.Compile()));
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with the dependency free solution but I'll keep this in mind.